# Are there more learnable but undecidable cases except the halting problem

Tags: computability, lg.learning

Per request, I cross post the question here which is original from [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3742119/are-there-more-learnable-but-undecidable-cases-except-the-halting-problem)

In the ICML 1996 paper, *On the Learnability of the Uncomputables*, by Richard Lathrop, he proved that halting problem is learnable in a probabilistic learnability. So except halting problem, are there more undecidable cases which can be learned?

For example, the Chaitin's halting probability $\Omega$ is uncomputable, but if we gives enough many random sample programs and then wait for enough long time, and treat the non-stop program as not halting, we might be possible to approach the constant $\Omega$. And please check [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1699366/can-we-know-the-first-few-digits-of-chaitins-constant/)

And I think the above idea is similar to the idea in Richard Lathrop's paper.

Few people talk about this paper which seems to be important, because the conclusion makes us more clear on the relationship of computable and learnable. I am also curious about the reason.

- [On the Learnability of the Uncomputables](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/On-the-Learnability-of-the-Uncomputable-Lathrop/7ecc6f1fdae66a15c6b105955dea2ac795e5b1b2) by Richard Lathrop

Comment: Please see this question, and my answer there:
https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/39222/functions-that-are-not-efficiently-computable-but-learnable/39247#39247